# Paypal donations with summary in Joomla

Tags: joomla, paypal, donations

I'm working on a joomla site for a charity event.  The event has 5 causes to donate for each with its own page.  I have created paypal donation buttons for each of the five causes using this site: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_donate-intro-outside.  That all works fine but I need to accomplish two more things.  1) How do I display a summary of the donations for each cause on its respective page and 2) How do I display a total donations received across all 5 causes on the home page?

I am currently going into the paypal account and updating these values manually every night.  I know there has to be a better way.  I think I have to do something with IPN but I can't find any good documentation.  I'm not a php programmer so I need some hand holding but I can get through it with some help.

I have searched high and low for a Joomla extension to do this but I just can't seem to find anything that fits my situation.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to pull this off without some PHP programming and a good integration with Joomla.

As a *general overview* you will have to:

- activate and configure IPN (Instant Payment Notifications) in PayPal
- for your buttons configure the notify_url (the URL where PayPal should send the IPN)
- on the Joomla site you will have to process those notifications and save into a database the transaction information that you get
- finally - on each of your pages you will have to do a database look up and compute the totals that you require.

I have used Jumi (Joomla extension) to implement something similar to what you need, but it does require a lot of PHP programming to do it like this.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  That's what I figured I needed to do, I just need to figure out how.

Comment: I think you will need a PHP/Joomla programmer to help you. This is not very advanced, but it's not beginner either.